# increase the size of div on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css

I want to increase the size of the div when mouse hover over the div.
The div should come over other div's which are all ready there on the page.
Every thing working fine except the size keep increases and decreases multiple times when I pass mouse many time on the div.

```
.news {
background-color: #ECEEF1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C46211;
border-right: 1px solid #C46211;
color: #000000;
float: right;
height: 24px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 8px;
width: 600px;
```

}

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4FcV/183/ to show the example.

Comment: jquery wasn't necessary at all. you could achieve the same with little CSS. I bet you might have tried it out. Here is my example: **http://jsfiddle.net/h4FcV/193/**

Comment: He needs an animate to grow and shrink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$(this).clearQueue()` to both `hover`-functions (just after your CSS-modifications).

By the way: you can reduce your code by place the CSS-rules in one `$(this).css()`-rule like this:

```
 $(this).css({

    "property": "value",
    "property": "value"

 });
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [**clearQueue()**](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)    `$(this).clearQueue();`

> When the .clearQueue() method is called, all functions on the queue that have not been executed are removed from the queue

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4FcV/189/)

Answer (score 2):

Please add this

```
 $(function () {
        $("#div1").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).animate({
                "width": "70%",
                "height": window.innerHeight + "px"
            });
            $(this).css("zindex","100");
            $(this).css("position","absolute");
            $(this).css("background-color","#efef3f");

        },

        function () {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).animate({
                "width": "50%",
                "height": ""
            });
            $(this).css("zindex","1");
            $(this).css("position","relative");
             $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
        });
    });
```

Please add only $(this).stop(); before applying the effect .animate().

It will works for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.stop()` before the `.animate({})`-method. It makes jQuery stop the current animation(s) before it starts the new one.

You can see how it works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4FcV/188/

Comment: If you do that then the animate is slower when it restarts

Answer (score 1):

Use this js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#div1").hover(

    function () {
        if($(this).css('height') === '100px') {
        $(this).animate({
            "width": "70%",
                "height": window.innerHeight + "px"
        });
        $(this).css("z-index", "100");
        $(this).css("position", "absolute");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#efef3f");
        }

    },

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "width": "50%",
                "height": ""
        });
        $(this).css("z-index", "1");
        $(this).css("position", "relative");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/h4FcV/194/

Comment: This makes the animation play multiple times if you mousein and out fast, add a .stop() to it

Comment: No it only plays the animate if the height is the original height of the div

Comment: i just broke it by running my mouse in and out really fast

Comment: oh that is really weird

Comment: Every time the height is 100px it's queuing an animation, since you aren't clearing the queue the animations will play out.